# Curved View in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, view

I am trying to create a view to implicate a swiping feature in a table view like the picture below.  [image]

I just want to curve one side of a view in equally to imply a swiping gesture. Is this easy to do in code?  Or is it better to mask an image over the view? Please suggest.

Comment: Do you just want that drawing, or do you want to "notch" any arbitrary view?

Comment: Either would work as I just have view underneath this one that is unveiled as you swipe left.

Comment: So why not use your actual image as the image? No need to draw it in code (although you certainly can if you want to); just have the image sitting there waiting to be unveiled by the swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIView`, implement the `drawRect:` method and do that shape (either by drawing to the context, or by using a bezierPath).

Make sure you set the view to opaque, and the `backgroundColor` to `clearColor`.